# Problems with openni_camera + Groovy + Asus Xtion Pro

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, asus-xtion-pro, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I tried to report this bug in the appropriate issue tracker but I can't find where the Groovy version of OpenNi has been moved. It appears the [kforge](https://kforge.ros.org/openni/openni_camera) repo from the documentation is old.

When running "roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch" with an Asus Xtion Pro sensor I can see the image correctly using "rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color". However, the openni node soon seg faults and when I attempt to restart it I get the following errors:

```
INFO ros.openni_camera./camera/driver: Number devices connected: 1
INFO ros.openni_camera./camera/driver: 1. device on bus 002:04 is a Xtion Pro (600) from ASUS (1d27) with serial id ''
INFO ros.openni_camera./camera/driver: Searching for device with index = 1
INFO ros.openni_camera./camera/driver: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::OpenNIDevice(xn::Context&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&) @ /tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-openni-camera-1.8.0/debian/ros-groovy-openni-camera/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/openni_camera/src/openni_device.cpp @ 99 : creating depth generator failed. Reason: Got a timeout while waiting for a network command to complete!
```

And I am unable to reconnect until I restart my computer. Any thoughts on what I need to do to fix this, or what the developers can fix?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50376/problems-with-openni_camera-+-groovy-+-asus-xtion-pro/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2012-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've never that specific error. Before restarting your computer, can you do a :
killall -9 XnSensorServer
Are you on USB 1 and 2 ? (not 3) ?
Are you on shadow-fixed for Groovy ? Which version of openni-dev do you have installed ?

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2012-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-01-04**:
The openni drivers have been upgraded so I no longer get this exact error, but it still doesn't work. I'll post a new question.